# Random selection of ids from a file

Tags: awk, grep, shuffle

I have a text file in the following format, the alphabets are ids separated by a space.

```
OG1: A B C D E
OG2: C F G D R
OG3: A D F F F
```

I would like to randomly extract one id from each group as

```
OG1: E
OG2: D
OG3: A
```

I tried using

```
 shuf -n 1 data.txt
```

which gives me

```
 OG2: C F G D R
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{srand(seed)} {print $1,$(rand()*(NF-1)+2)}' file

OG1: D
OG2: F
OG3: F
```

to skip a certain letter, you can change the main block to

```
... {while ("C"==r=$(rand()*(NF-1)+2)); print $1,r}' file
```

Comment: this gives random between different runs too ++

Comment: Is it possible to always avoid one particular alphabet from the random selection say "C" in this case?

Answer (score 2):

`perl -lane 'print "$F[0] ".$F[rand($#F-1)+1]' data.txt`

Explanation:

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around each line of the input file
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the `@F` array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace.
- `-e` execute the perl code

`@F` is the array of words in each line, indexed starting with `$F[0]`
`$#F` is the number of words in `@F`

output:

```
OG1: A
OG2: F
OG3: F
```